# Wrapper element for svelte storybook

Tags: css, svelte, storybook

I am currently writing a component in svelte and in order to work on only this component I am also using storybook.

The problem is that because of the css library I am using the component will be incorrectly rendered unless it is properly wrapped by a parent element. In short, this component is list element and without the list wrapper the css will be funky.

So the question is, can I somehow tell storybook to wrap my component in a div?

i.e. something like this

```
storiesOf("Kanban card", module)
  .add(
    "small",
    () => ({
      Component: Card,
      template: "<div class='wrapper'><Card /></div>",
      props: {
        ...
      }
    })
  );
```

Comment: I think this is what story Decorators are for: https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-stories/decorators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a separate Svelte component, specifically for that story. This approach also gives you a way to use slots properly, something that's not clearly available through Storybook.

Something like `kanban-card.story.svelte` containing:

```html
<script>
  import Card from '../wherever/kanban-card.svelte';

  // export the props that the component needs
  // pass up all events you want to handle
</script>

<Card on:eventYouWant />
```

Comment: old post, but yeah I think that is what I did and it works

Comment: @munHunger for future generations :)